# Update only few fields of an entity whitout using multiple if

Tags: java, spring

I'm building an e-shop as an excercise to practice new things, I'm now at the point were i should made the service to edit the products, but i think it can be optimized somehow

I want to be able to change an undefined number of attributes.

Example: i may want to change the name on a product, then i may want to change the price and the availability status on another product

I managed to do such thing using multiple if statements for each attribute of the Product class

public ResponseEntity<?> editProduct(ProductsDto productDto){

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Optional<Products> oldProduct = productsRepository.findById(productDto.getId());

        if (oldProduct.isEmpty()){
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Product with id: "+productDto.getId()+" not found.");
        }
        
        if (!oldProduct.get().getName().equals(productDto.getName())){
            oldProduct.get().setName(productDto.getName());
        }
        if (!oldProduct.get().getPrice().equals(productDto.getPrice())){
            oldProduct.get().setPrice(productDto.getPrice());
        }
        if (!oldProduct.get().getQuantity().equals(productDto.getQuantity())){
            oldProduct.get().setQuantity(productDto.getQuantity());
        }

    /* n if statements for each attribute in the object */

        productsRepository.save(oldProduct.get());
    }catch(Exception e){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage());
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body("New Product added correctly");
}
```

There is a way i can make it more efficient, and maybe in a way that if i add an attribute in the object i don't need to add another if ?

Thanks

Java version 17

**---- EDIT ----**

The ProductDto class is not the same as the Products class, they have different attributes, for example Products references the user who created it

In the case where the productDto is a reflection of the Product class i could just update the product like this : `productsRepository.save(productDto);`

But what should i do in the case where the dto has only few of the fields valorized. I can't just save it, otherwise i'll lose some data

For example:

```
{
    "id":  "6",
    "name" : "Brioche",
    "price" : "",
    "quantity" : 10,
    "availableFrom" : "",
    "availableUntil" : "13/06/2023 10:00:00"
}
```

in this case im only changing the name, quantity and availableUntil

Comment: You really don't need the ifs, just set all attributes from DTO into the `Products` instance. Also I would consider a function like `updateProductsFromDTO()` that returns the updated `Products` instance instead of having that here.

Comment: I believe the dto is a different class so that can't easily be swapped like this

Comment: You don't need to check equality of fields because in any case nothing will be changed in your entity even if set field which are equal. So your `if` are redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the simplest solition may be the following.

If someone needs to edit a product or anything, it should get all the attribute first. From a front end point of wiew i have to do a GET request to get the fields value to be displaied, then i need to submit the infos to the backend
Instead of submitting just the edited attributes, the front end will submit evrything, old values + the new values

Of course in the backend there will be some checks to prevent changing attribute such as the primary key ecc.

I don't think this is the best practice, for sure there is soething better, but it works and I think it's saving a lot of useless code

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to copy all the fields? or just a part of them? is your `dto` a different class (ProductDto) or is it an instance of Product? One option would be to use something like this:

```java
Product update = mapToProduct(dto);
Product product = oldProduct.get(); 
product.update(update);
```

And, add the update method in the Product class:

```java
class Product {
    String name;
    String price;
    String quantity;

    public void update(Product other) {
        name = other.name;
        price = other.price;
        quantity = other.quantity;
    }
}
```

Or, you can also use BeanUtils like this:

```
public void update(Product other) {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(other, this);
}
```

It even allows you to ignore some of the fields, for example, the "id":

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(other, this, "id");
```

PS: I am not a big fan of `BeanUtils` and I would advise you not to use it on objects from different classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) you can use this aproach

This will be the equivalent to your "Products" class

```
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Entity {
  private int id;
  
  private String name;
  
  private double price;
  
  private int quantity;
  
  private DateTime availableFrom;
  
  private DateTime availableUntil;

  private List<String> references;
  
  private boolean moreVariables;
}
```

This the equivalent of the DTO example you gave to us

```
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class EntityDto {
  private Integer id;
  
  private String name;
  
  private Double price;
  
  private Integer quantity;
  
  private DateTime availableFrom;
  
  private DateTime availableUntil;
}
```

This is the approach to overwrite only the given parameters (not null) to the old product entity

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.MappingTarget;
import org.mapstruct.NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

@Mapper(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
public interface MapperExample {

  void updateEntity(@MappingTarget Entity entity, final EntityDto dto);
  
}
```

Then when you compile the project is as easy as this to call the mapper

```
public class YourClass {
  @Autowired
  private MapperExample mapper;

  ...

  public ResponseEntity<?> editProduct(EntityDto dto) { 
    Optional<Entity> entity = productsRepository.findById(dto.getId());
    mapper.updateEntity(entity.get(), dto);
    productsRepository.save(entity.get());

  ...

  }
}
```

PD: @AllArgsConstructor and @Data are [Lombok annotations](https://projectlombok.org/features/) that helps to avoid writing extra code like constructors or all getters and setters.

Here you have some links to the documentation of MapStruct if you need more info about [@Mapper](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Mapper.html) or [@MappingTarget](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/MappingTarget.html) annotations